# Best way to fetch only value in single-element php array

Tags: php, arrays

If I want to fetch the arrays only value, and an unknown key, what's the best way to do it?

one way to do it:

```
if(count($list) == 1)
{
   $value = implode('', $list);
   ....
```

insted of implode, you can use `array_values($list)[0]`
or maybe

```
if(count($list) == 1)
{
   foreach($list as $value)
   {
      ....
```

what more ways can you get the value, and is there a 'best' way?

Comment: You mean, always the first value?

Comment: @fschmengler if the list only have one value, its both the first and the last value too.

Comment: Ah, I thought "only value" meant "value, but not key". Now the question makes sense.

Comment: If the list has only one value then how can there be `both` the first and last values?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I can think of:

**Using [`reset`](http://php.net/reset):**

```
echo reset($list);
```

**Using [`key`](http://php.net/key):**

```
echo $list[key($list)];
```

**Using [`end`](http://php.net/end):**

```
echo end($list);
```

**Using [`current`](http://php.net/current):**

```
echo current($list);
```

**Using [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):**

```
echo array_shift(array_slice($list,0,1));
```

**Using [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):**

```
echo array_values($list)[0];
```

**Using [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):**

```
echo array_shift(array_values($list));
```

Some of the above functions rely on the array's internal pointer, which, if not moved, always is at the first entry of the array.

However when it comes to determining which option is the *best*, I couldn't really tell. I hardly believe that there is one *best* option.

Comment: as long as I don't need the list to something else, array_pop(), and array_shift() should work to

Answer (score 2):

In the situation you're describing, there is no 'best' way.  Consider this solution:

```
if(count($list) == 1)
{
  $value = reset($list);
}
```

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

> reset() rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and
>   returns the value of the first array element.
>
> Returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is
>   empty.

Another solution could use the [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function:

```
if(count($list) == 1)
{
  $value = end($list);
}
```

> end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

Comment: Why that count check?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i added the count check because that's what was in the OP

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a *best* option for every context, but here are some considerations on the alternatives:

1. ```
   $value = implode('', $list);
   ```

   This converts the value to string. If the array is empty or has more than one value, there will be no error, instead you get an empty string or all values concatenated
2. ```
   $value = reset($list);
   ```

   This has the side effect of setting the internal array pointer. The result is `false` if the array is empty. In arrays with more than one element, you'll get the first item

   - Variation: `end($list)` - the same, but you'll get the last item if the array has more than one item.
3. ```
   $value = current($list);
   ```

   This works without side effect but assumes that the internal array pointer has not been advanced to the end of the array before (i.e. with `next()` or a loop). Otherwise (or with empty arrays), the result is `false`.

   - Variation: `$list[key($list)]` - the same, but results in an error instead of `false`, if array is empty or pointer at the end.
4. ```
   $value = array_values($list)[0];
   ```

   No side effects, always returns the first value. Throws an error if the array is empty. Does not work in ancient PHP versions (older than 5.4) because array dereferencing.